# Form validation on visible fields at that moment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a form as follows:

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">
    <input type="checkbox" id="HomeType" name="HomeType" ng-model="ModelData.HomeType"
        ng-checked="ModelData.HomeType == 'T'" />
    Show Home Type 1
</label>

<!--This is visible only if above checkbox is selected-->                       
<div class="form-group" ng-if="ModelData.HomeType1">
    <label for="HomeType1" class="col-md-3 control-label">
        Type of Home:
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : MyForm.HomeType1.$invalid && submitted}">
        <select id="HomeType1" name="HomeType1" class="form-control"
            ng-model="ModelData.HomeType1" ng-options="Home.HomeType as Home.HomeDescription for Home in HomeTypeTable"
            required>
        </select>
        <span ng-show="MyForm.HomeType1.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">
            Please select the Type of Home 1.</span>
    </div>
</div>

<!--This is always visible on the screen-->                     
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="HomeType2" class="col-md-3 control-label">
        Type of Home 2:
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : MyForm.HomeType2.$invalid && submitted}">
        <select id="HomeType2" name="HomeType2" class="form-control"
            ng-model="ModelData.HomeType2" ng-options="Home.HomeType as Home.HomeDescription for Home in HomeTypeTable"
            required>
        </select>
        <span ng-show="MyForm.HomeType2.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">
            Please select the Type of Home 2.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, Home Type 2 dropdown is always visible and Home Type 1 is visible only on selection of the checkbox.

Now, on click of form submit button, I set the $scope.submitted variable to true and stops the submission as follows:

```
$scope.submitted = true;
if($scope.MyForm.$invalid == true){
return false;
}
```

So, this brings the red colored bolder to my Home Type 2 dropdown. Till this everything is fine. If I select any value to Home Type 2 dropdown, the red color is gone and I am able to submit the form also (as Home Type 1 is still hidden, so it is not validated).

But the problem comes when I do as follows:

1. Lets say my Home Type 2 is blank and Home Type 1 checkbox is not selected (so Home Type 1 is hidden) and I try to submit the form.
2. This triggers submit and makes Home Type 2 red. And stops the submission.
3. Then I selected the Home Type 1 checkbox, so it makes Home Type 1 visible on the screen. But this Home Type 1 is also in red color !!
4. I want to validate this Home Type 1 dropdown only when form is submitted and this field was visible at that submission. If Home Type 1 was hidden at the time of submission, it should not be red when it is made visible if user selects checkbox after first submission attempt.

Hopefully I was able to explain my situation.

Comment: can you make a plnkr/fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of trying, I implemented this myself:

```
//1. Create a New Directive
angular.module('ipRequired', []).directive("ipRequired", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            console.log('init');
            console.log(scope.InvalidFields);

            scope.InvalidFields[attrs.name] = false;

            console.log('after');
            console.log(scope.InvalidFields);

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                delete scope.InvalidFields[attrs.name];       //this will remove the property from InvalidFields object on removal of field from screen

                console.log('destroy');
                console.log(scope.InvalidFields);
            });
        }
    };
});


//2. add this in your Controller's submit module
$scope.InvalidFields = {};  //add also at the beginning of every controller

$scope.InvalidFields = {};  //reset
angular.forEach($scope.InsuredPortalForm.$error.required, function (field) {
    this[field.$name] = true;   //adding current 'invalid' field into $scope.InvalidFields object (passed as 'this' in forEach context)
}, $scope.InvalidFields);



//3. add this in every required field
//as InvalidFields.FieldName like InvalidFields.ExpirationCancellationDate
<div class="form-group datefielddiv" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : InsuredPortalForm.ExpirationCancellationDate.$invalid && submitted && InvalidFields.ExpirationCancellationDate}">
       <input  type="tel" class="col-md-2 form-control datefield" id="ExpirationCancellationDate"
                     name="ExpirationCancellationDate" ng-model="ModelData.ExpirationCancellationDate"
                     ip-regex="date" 
                     ng-required="ModelData.InsuranceOnProperty == 'Y' || ModelData.PrevInsExpDays == 'A'" 
                     ip-required />
       <img alt="calendar" src="img/calendar.png" class="calendarimage" />
       <span ng-show="InsuredPortalForm.ExpirationCancellationDate.$invalid && submitted && InvalidFields.ExpirationCancellationDate"
              class="help-block">Previous Policy Expiration/Cancellation Date is Required.</span>
</div>
```